# NHibernate joining on incorrect field

Tags: .net, nhibernate, join

I am very new to Nhibernate, I know what my issue is however unsure how to fix it.

Issue: The user is joined to a employee via the EmployeeID rather than the UserID. Which is causing issues as it is bringing back incorrect details.

```
Employee.hbm.xml
<many-to-one name="User" unique="true" column="UserID" />

User.hbm.xml
<one-to-one name="Employee" foreign-key="EmployeeID" class="Employee" lazy="false" />

Employee.cs
public virtual int EmployeeID { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; } - This is UserID within the actual database
public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }

User.cs
public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
public virtual string Username { get; set; }
public virtual string Title { get; set; }
public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

Above is what someone else has coded and I'm trying to fix it. I tried changing

```
<one-to-one name="Employee" foreign-key="UserID" class="Employee" lazy="false" />
```

however this still causes issues.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Clare

**UPDATE**

I was hoping by making it one-to-one that it would join on the UserID, however it is still joining on the EmployeeID. Anyone have any other ideas? Thanks again :-)

```
Employee.hbm.xml
<one-to-one name="User" foreign-key="UserID" class="User" lazy="false" />

User.hbm.xml
<one-to-one name="Employee" foreign-key="UserID" class="Employee" lazy="false" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `many-to-one` instead of a `one-to-one`?

Comment: How is your foreign key on the User a UserID? Would this not be the primary?

Answer (score 1):

**You shouldn't specify any column name in a** `one-to-one` **mapping**, because that piece of information is part of the `many-to-one` mapping on the other side of the relationship.

In order to solve your problem you should remove the `foreign-key` attribute from the `one-to-one` mapping on the `User` entity:

```
<one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" lazy="false" />
```

NHibernate will use the information in the `many-to-one` mapping defined on the `Employee` entity to build the SQL statements.

**Note** that if an `Employee` always has a `User` associated to it (i.e. the `Employee.User` property can never be `null`) then you should state this fact in the `one-to-one`mapping by adding the `constrained` attribute:

```
<one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" constrained="true" lazy="false" />
```

**Related resources:**

- [NHibernate Mapping - <one-to-one />](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx)

Comment: Hello Enrico, I have removed foreign-key but it still seems to be joining on the UserID - EmployeeID. I have looked through the code and it doesn't seem to join EmployeeID - UserID? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to your entities there is not a one to one relationship between user and employee.  Please see this explanation:</strike>

http://jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/

I think you need to specifiy your one to one as a many-to-one instead.

**Edit:**
I think I may have misunderstood your scenario.
You may want to use `property-ref` here.  So you're mapping would look like this:

```
<one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" property-ref="User" lazy="false" />
```

Please check out the following link for more detail:  [Nhibernate Documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)

Also there is a similar post on SO here: [one-to-one and specifying column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776194/one-to-one-and-specifying-column)

Comment: Hello Cole, I do want it to be a one-to-one relationship though. Please see update above

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I was moved onto another project. I will give it a go and let you know. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a many-to-one relationship here because I am aware you may want to merge User accounts and one-to-one may cause problems with moving an employee record to the merged user.

If you treat it like your User can have multiple Employee records then this avoids this problem.

Have you tried something like the following:

Employee.hbm.xml

User.hbm.xml

http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one